# How to show video ads on iphone?

Tags: iphone, ios

I have tried Flurry ads but i am not able to see any video ads (its a static image). I have followed this **http://support.flurry.com/index.php?title=Publisher/Code**
Are there any other frameworks that help me to achieve this ?